# Lookup/reference tables in graph databases

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j, lookup-tables

How do we model/represent lookup/reference tables in graph databases?
One specific case: master translation table (contains lookup data for many of the core tables).
Should we merge them into core tables?
[RDBMS representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftlof.png)

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example? Keep in mind there is no concept of tables in a graph database.

Comment: I've added an image of current RDBMS representation into the post. 
<br/>
One of the solutions is to create another attribute for each of the nodes, that will contain translation of the codes (:"Core tab 2"({col2:'NY', col2_description:'New York'})) <br/>
Another solution is to keep the codes' descriptions in separate table and use some function to translate it every time we need it.

Answer (score 1):

You could model this with just nodes. Something like:

```
CREATE (:Translation{code:'SLD', description:'some lengthy description'})
CREATE (:Translation{code:'NY', description:'New York'})
CREATE (:Translation{code:'USA', description:'United States'})
CREATE (:Address{address:'123 Street St', state:'NY', country:'USA'})
```

And for usage maybe something like:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVES_AT]->(a:Address)
WHERE id(p) = 101
OPTIONAL MATCH (state:Translation{code:a.state})
OPTIONAL MATCH (country:Translation{code:a.country})
RETURN a.address as address, state.description as state, country.description as country
```

That said, I think a graph database makes the need for these somewhat obsolete. Seems to me that the reason to use these is to save on space because the same values are used repeatedly, so in RDBMS it makes sense to only keep the longer description in one place.

With a graph, that seems to suggest you should extract out the value to its own node and create relationships to it, like this:

```
CREATE (ny:State{code:'NY', name:'New York'})
CREATE (usa:Country{code:'USA', name:'United States})
CREATE (a:Address{address:'123 Street St'})
CREATE (a)-[:IN_STATE]->(ny)    // or a more generic :IN if desired
CREATE (a)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(usa) // or a more generic :IN if desired
```

The query would then become:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:LIVES_AT]->(a:Address)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:IN_STATE]->(state)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:IN_COUNTRY]->(country)
RETURN a.address as address, state.name as state, country.name as country
```

You'll note this looks very similar. The long country name is still only stored in one place. The real difference is context, both for working with nodes with particular labels and possibly more specific property keys, and with having the relationship to these nodes be part of your data model, rather than having to somehow know or guess that certain property fields can be looked up in a different node (for example, try `CALL db.schema()` in the browser).

This also makes it easier to lookup addresses by the code, if you add an index on :State(code) and :Country(code).

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense, especially for such cases as in your examples. Note: creating separate nodes also allows to store codes/descriptions even for those situations when "core" records don't have such values (works both for RDBMS and graph databases).